# Acessar elementos baseado em variável

Tags: c#

Preciso atribuir o valor a uma *label*, exemplo: `xrLabel1.text = "teste"`, mas como possuo várias *labels* onde muda somente o número no final exemplo:

```
xrLabel1.text = "teste";
xrLabel2.text = "teste";
xrLabel3.text = "teste";
```

Como faço para preencher estes valores utilizando um *loop* como no exemplo abaixo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    string.Concat("xrLabel", i.ToString()).Text = "teste";
```

Comment: Não, existem mais de 100 *labels* que preciso mudar, é inviável fazer na mão.

Comment: Qual a classe dos *labels*?

Comment: Classe **XRLabel**. É uma label do relatório **DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport**. Preciso fazer em todas, é um relatório bem específico onde não tenho como usar um grid com *DataDource* pois são dados muito distintos e então tenho que setar individualmente.

Comment: No **php** esse tipo de coisa é muito fácil de se fazer. Chamar uma função com nome variável por exemplo: `$variable = "my_function"; MyClass->$variable();`. Mas aqui no C# não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode pesquisar o objeto pelo nome:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    XRLabel label = (XRLabel)this.Controls[string.Concat("xrLabel", i.ToString())];
    label.text = "teste"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de fazer isto seria usar uma [expressão LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397676.aspx) para selecionar todos os *labels* do formulário, e com o [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) iterar sobre a lista de *labels* e o resultado do `select` do `DataTable`:

```
// Simulando os dados do teu DataTable
DataTable tabela = new DataTable("Jogadores");
tabela.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Nome",  typeof(string)));
tabela.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Idade", typeof(int)));
tabela.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sexo",  typeof(char)));

tabela.Rows.Add("Maria",   20, 'f');
tabela.Rows.Add("Leticia", 25, 'f');
tabela.Rows.Add("Pedro",   30, 'm');
tabela.Rows.Add("Tiago",   40, 'm');
tabela.Rows.Add("Joao",    29, 'm');

// Selecionar linhas onde o campo idade seja maior ou igual a 29
DataRow[] resultados = tabela.Select("Idade >= 29");

// No caso do AP ele usou this.Controls["PageHeader"].AllControls<XRLabel>()
var labels = this.Controls.OfType<XRLabel>(); 

foreach (var tupla in labels.Zip(resultados, Tuple.Create)){
    XRLabel label = tupla.Item1 as XRLabel;
    string valor = tupla.Item2.Field<String>(0); // Valor do campo "Nome"
    label.Text = valor;
}
```

Comment: Preciso fazer em todas mas para cada uma preciso colocar um valor diferente. O meu *Select* retorna um *DataTable* contendo um valor específico para cada *label*.

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Dessa maneira acredito que também funcione, mas a resposta [acima](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64873/14645) se adequou melhor ao que eu preciso. Muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @DanielLourusso Disponha. Editei a resposta e coloquei um código que deverá servir para o teu cenário, espero que ajude. =)

Comment: Perfeito. Mas ao testar aqui, no meu caso usei assim: `this.Controls["PageHeader"].Controls.OfType<XRLabel>();`. Obtive o seguinte erro:
`'DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControlCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
Como faço?

Comment: Encontrei, basta usar `this.Controls["PageHeader"].AllControls<XRLabel>()`